# Genetic Algorithm giving same data every time

Tags: java, collections, genetic-algorithm

I am trying too implement GA in java to solve equations(not important at this moment)

I have a class for Chromosome implementing Comparable (to sort by fitness) 
and my own IChromosome interface.

I have provided functions for cross over , mutation , etc in this class:
some things like this:

```
public interface IChromosome
{

    public int getSize();
    public void setSize(int s);

    public IGene[] getGenes();
    public void setGenes(IGene[] genes);

    public IGene getGene(int i);
    public void setGene(int i , IGene val);

    public double getFitness();

    public IChromosome[] crossOver(IChromosome c2);
    public IChromosome mutate();

}
```

And Main part of my GA programs is this:

```
public class GeneticAlgorithm
{
    final int populationSize;
    int crossOverRate;// Probability in persent
    int mutationRate;// Probability in persent
    int elitismRate;// in persent
    int TournamentNumber;//number of random Chromosomes to compete in Tournament


    int repeatCount;


    Chromosome [] currentGeneration;
    Chromosome [] nextGeneration;


    public GeneticAlgorithm(int populationSize, int crossOverRate, int mutationRate, int ElitismRate, int TournamentNumber)
    {
        this.populationSize = populationSize;
        this.crossOverRate = crossOverRate;
        this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
        this.elitismRate = ElitismRate;
        this.TournamentNumber = TournamentNumber;

        repeatCount = 0;

        currentGeneration = new Chromosome[populationSize];
        nextGeneration = new Chromosome[populationSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            currentGeneration[i] =new Chromosome(Chromosome.getPolynomial().getSize());//Also randomize it; //size is from another class
        }

    }


    private Chromosome[] select()
    {
        Chromosome[] temp = new Chromosome[TournamentNumber];

        //choose populationSize random uniqe number
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            nums.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(nums);


        for (int i = 0; i < TournamentNumber; i++)
        {
            temp[i]=new Chromosome(currentGeneration[nums.get(i)]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(temp);
        Chromosome[] res = new Chromosome[2];

        //choosing best Chromosomes
        res[0] = new Chromosome(temp[TournamentNumber-1]);
        res[1] = new Chromosome(temp[TournamentNumber-2]);
        return res;
    }


    public void repeat()
    {
        repeatCount++;

        Arrays.sort(currentGeneration,Collections.reverseOrder());
        int elitism = (populationSize*elitismRate)/100;

        for (int i = 0; i < elitism ; i++)
        {
            nextGeneration[i] = new Chromosome(currentGeneration[i]);
        }

        int cop = 0;//Cross Over Probability
        int mp;//mutation Probability
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Chromosome [] sel;
        Chromosome [] temp;
        Chromosome ch1 , ch2;
        for (int i = elitism; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            cop = rnd.nextInt(100);
            sel = new Chromosome[2];
            sel = select();
            if(cop <= crossOverRate)
            {
                temp = (Chromosome[]) ( sel[0].crossOver(sel[1]) );//tested , And I 'm sure cross over function working well
                ch1 = temp[0];
                ch2 = temp[1];
            }
            else
            {
                ch1 = new Chromosome(sel[0]);
                ch2 = new Chromosome(sel[1]);
            }

            mp = rnd.nextInt(100);
            if(mp< mutationRate)
            {
                ch1.mutate();
            }
            nextGeneration[i]= new Chromosome(ch1);
            if(++i<populationSize)
            {
                nextGeneration[i]= new Chromosome(ch2);
            }
        }//for

        //copiny current generation to nextGeneration
        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            currentGeneration[i] = new Chromosome(nextGeneration[i]);
        }
    }//repeat 

}
```

Every thing seems to be normal but after a few generations (calling `repeat()` ) all of my Chromosomes in generation will be a save value.

I trued debugging program for many times , but I couldn't find any thing.

What can the problem be?

Comment: *all of my Chromosomes in generation will be a save value.*  sorry but I didn't get you.

Comment: Is there a period of time where they aren't all the same, or are they always all the same? The latter would make me think maybe you're setting the seed for the random number generator to a fixed value somewhere.

Comment: @seaotternerd in first generations all of them are not same . after a few repeats all of them will be same

Comment: @TAsk it means all of  Chromosomes I have in current generation are one thing for example all of them are [10,20,30] (numbers are genes)

Comment: You haven't shown us `Chromosome.java`, so this is going to be a guess, but is it possible that your Chromosomes are sharing the arrays they use to represent genes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks your algorithm has early convergence, if other things are OK.

possible solutions are:
1- set Elitism Rate to zero;
2- reduce crossover rate;
3- increase mutation rate.

also if the problem being solved is very simple, GA early convergence is natural.